Presto setup with Hive and Hadoop: Error loading Hadoop native library
I am trying to configure a single-node Presto on a machine where Hive is up and running too, a 3-node Hadoop cluster is also installed and running in separate 3 machines. Below are my configurations:
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Java: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Presto version: presto-server-0.272
Hive Machine IP: 192.168.AB.004
Hadoop Machine Masternode IP: 192.168.AB.001
I have set up Presto with the following configurations:
/etc/config.properties
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=1GB
query.max-memory-per-node=512MB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://192.168.AB.004:8080

/etc/jvm.config
-server
-Xmx16G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native


/etc/log.properties
com.facebook.presto=WARN


/etc/node.properties
node.environment=production
node.id=f7c4bf3c-dbb4-4807-baae-9b7e41807bA9
node.data-dir=/home/user/presto/data/etc

I've also created a /catalog folder with two files:
/catalog/hive.properties
connector.name=hive-hadoop2
hive.metastore.uri=thrift://192.168.AB.001:9083 ## it is a hadoop master node
hive.config.resources=/home/user/hadoopnode/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml,/home/user/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/conf/hive-site.xml


/catalog/jmx.properties
connector.name=jmx


However, when I try to start Presto using /bin/launcher start, it starts with a PID, but after some time, when I check its status using /bin/launcher status, it states "NOT working".
Inspecting the server.log file, I found the following errors:
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load Hadoop native library
...
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/hadoop15893511666224505815.tmp: /tmp/hadoop15893511666224505815.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object


Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I was having the same problem and found that the underlying error failed to map segment from shared object can be caused by using a filesystem that has the noexec restriction.
In my case I added -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/new/tmp to the jvm.config and it worked
